# how to resize custom svg marker using data setStyle on geojson point feature

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

This should be fairly trivial to fix but I cant figure out why my custom marker disappears when I set the icon width and height.

The svg icon appears fine on the map before trying to resize it... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/pzhjc6d7

But when I add the sizing params via the `map.data.setStyle` icon array, my marker disappears.

```js
var geoJson_features = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "id": 70,
      "name": "roman coin"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
       -0.7318782806396484375,
        51.8924376272136740340
      ]
    }
  }]
};

function initialize() {

  // map properties
  var mapProp = {
    zoom: 17,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [
        google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        'night_hawk_style'
      ],
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
      backgroundColor: 'none'
    }
  };

  // google map object
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);

  // load GeoJSON.
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {

    // load GeoJSON.
    map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson_features);

    // create empty bounds object
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // loop through features
    map.data.forEach(function(feature) {

      // get the features geometry
      var geo = feature.getGeometry();

      // loop through each coordinate
      geo.forEachLatLng(function(LatLng) {
        bounds.extend(LatLng);
      });

    });

    // fit data to bounds
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

  });


  // map data styles based on geo json properties
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {

    // statusColor
    var statusColor = 'transparent';

    // check feature property status
    if (feature.getProperty('status')) {
      statusColor = feature.getProperty('status');
    }

    // return the style for the feature
    return ({
      icon: {

        // set svg icon svg
        url: 'https://svgshare.com/i/8tN.svg',

        // this marker is 14 pixels wide by 12 pixels high.
        //size: new google.maps.Size(14, 12),

        // the origin for this image is (0, 0).
        //origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),

        // The anchor for this image is the base (0, 12).
        //anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 12)

      }
    });

  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="googleMap"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

As soon as start adding these parameters below, my custom marker disappears. And there are no errors in the console.

```
return ({
  icon: {

    // set svg icon svg
    url: 'https://svgshare.com/i/8tN.svg',

    // this marker is 14 pixels wide by 12 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(14, 12),

    // the origin for this image is (0, 0).
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),

    // The anchor for this image is the base (0, 12).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 12)

  }
});
```

Can anyone help understand whats going wrong here. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To scale that icon, set its `scaledSize` to the desired size (and the `anchor` where you want it, middle of the base seems a little strange to me, but it that is what you want, use `Size(7,12)` as below):

```
map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
  // statusColor
  var statusColor = 'transparent';
  // check feature property status
  if (feature.getProperty('status')) {
    statusColor = feature.getProperty('status');
  }
  // return the style for the feature
  return ({
    icon: {
      // set svg icon svg
      url: 'https://svgshare.com/i/8tN.svg',
      // this marker is 765.9 pixels wide by 666 pixels high.
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(14, 12),
      // The anchor for this image is the base (0, 12).
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 12)
    }
  });
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/3mLck45p/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  // map properties
  var mapProp = {
    zoom: 17,
    zoomControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [
        google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        'night_hawk_style'
      ],
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL,
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_RIGHT,
      backgroundColor: 'none'
    }
  };
  // google map object
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
  var measle = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {
      lng: -0.7318782806396484375,
      lat: 51.8924376272136740340
    },
    map: map,
    icon: {
      url: "https://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/markers2/measle.png",
      size: new google.maps.Size(7, 7),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(4, 4)
    }
  });
  // load GeoJSON.
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    // load GeoJSON.
    map.data.addGeoJson(geoJson_features);
    // create empty bounds object
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    // loop through features
    map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
      // get the features geometry
      var geo = feature.getGeometry();
      // loop through each coordinate
      geo.forEachLatLng(function(LatLng) {
        bounds.extend(LatLng);
      });
    });
    // fit data to bounds
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });
  // map data styles based on geo json properties
  map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
    // statusColor
    var statusColor = 'transparent';
    // check feature property status
    if (feature.getProperty('status')) {
      statusColor = feature.getProperty('status');
    }
    // return the style for the feature
    return ({
      icon: {
        // set svg icon svg
        url: 'https://svgshare.com/i/8tN.svg',
        // this marker is 765.9 pixels wide by 666 pixels high.
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(14, 12),
        // The anchor for this image is the base (0, 12).
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(7, 12)
      }
    });
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
var geoJson_features = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "id": 70,
      "name": "roman coin"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [-0.7318782806396484375,
        51.8924376272136740340
      ]
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<div id="googleMap"></div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return the icon in your initialize function, you should set your icon to a new object with the new properties.

```
const icon = {

    // set svg icon svg
    url: 'https://svgshare.com/i/8tN.svg',

    // this marker is 14 pixels wide by 12 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(14, 12),

    // the origin for this image is (0, 0).
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),

    // The anchor for this image is the base (0, 12).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 12)

  }
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: icon,
        map: map
      });
```

Comment: The reason i'm returning it for each feature because i'm intending on changing the icon image based of the feature properties. But I cant shrink my icon size to the size that i'm specifying. I've tried adding your script to see if actually resizes but i'm not implementing it right. Can you make your script work here... https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/7fo6qwn3/2/ ?

Comment: Oh its an SVG sorry about that my example was for a PNG, do you have your path for your svg file? They work a little bit different, but unless you really have to stretch your marker I would go with png for simplicity

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/symbols

Comment: ah perfect dude i'm guna try this now cheers! The thing with a png, on retina it be blurry, I've tried scaling my png which is naturally 28x24 down to 14x12, but google.maps.size just seems to crop my png. Which doesn't helping sizing it down for retina devices. See my png issue here https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/pzhjc6d7/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ed7uyx2n/10/

very minimalistic example on your custom marker stretching it.

remember to keep aspect ratio. cheers!

Comment: Thanks for you help dude but other dude helped me with `scaledSize` parameter. Worked a charm with SVG. https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/3mLck45p/